# Want to update 2 input state values dynamically without recursive calls

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, infinite-recursion

I am making a React application for a currency converter website. I have two `<input>` fields where the user can input the number to get the exchange rate as shown here:
[Screenshot of Component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1sddl.png)

The `<input>` fields are as follows:

```
<>
  <input
    id="1"
    placeholder="0"
    type="number"
    value={state1.value}
    onChange={handleChange}
    disabled={loading}
  />

// rest of the component

  <input
    id="2"
    placeholder="0"
    type="number"
    value={state2.value}
    onChange={handleChange}
    disabled={loading}
  />
```

The states for the input fields are:

```
const [state1, setState1] = useState({
    value: '',
    currency: 'USD',
    src: 'https://hatscripts.github.io/circle-flags/flags/us.svg',
});
const [state2, setState2] = useState({
    value: '',
    currency: 'INR',
    src: 'https://hatscripts.github.io/circle-flags/flags/in.svg',
});
```

I want the `state2` to be updated when the user types in `state1`. And vice-versa. I don't want the auto-update of `state2` again changing `state1`. The state change should happen only when the user gives input.

I have tried using session state to avoid unnecessary API calls. It solves the problem except for the infinite recursion.

I have already written a `useEffect` for `state1` which works as expected. Now I want to do the same for `state2` without an infinite useEffect loop.

```
async function fetchCurrencyRate1(from, to) {
    setLoading(true);
    try {
        const response = await axios.get('http://localhost:4000/convert', {
            params: {
                from: from.currency,
                to: to.currency,
            },
        });
        setState2((state2) => ({
            ...state2,
            value: (from.value * response.data.value).toFixed(4),
        }));
        console.log(response.data);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
    }
    setLoading(false);
}

useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
        state1.value && fetchCurrencyRate1(state1, { ...state2 });
        if (state1.value === '') setState2({ ...state2, value: '' });
    }, 2000);
}, [state1]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The infinite render occurs because the `useEffect` of `state1` will fire each time `state1` take a new value and since inside the effect you update `state2` and this triggers `useEffect` of `state2` and the code there updates `state1` then `useEffect` of `state1` will be called infinitely because `state1` is an object so its value is always new.

you don't need `useEffect` for that, also you don't want to rerender the component twice on each input change you can simply make two separate `handleChange` functions for each input and make your logic in each one of them 
something like this:

```js
const handleChangeOne = async (e) => {
  // you can fetch data here instead
  setState1((prev) => {
    return {
      ...prev,
      value: e.target.value,
    };
  });
  setState2((prev) => {
    return {
      ...prev,
      value: (from.value * response.data.value).toFixed(4), 
    };
  });
};
const handleChangeTwo = async (e) => {
  // fetch data
  setState2((prev) => {
    return {
      ...prev,
      value: Number(e.target.value),
    };
  });
  setState1((prev) => {
    //
    return {
      ...prev,
      value: (from.value * response.data.value).toFixed(4),
    };
  });
};
```

Comment: I tried this approach. But it has a problem. The state changes only on the next render. The data is fetched in the same cycle. But the state is updated only in the next render cycle.

Comment: Maybe because you update based on state1 and state2 values, you dont do that

Comment: You have to make your logic based on e.target.value instead dont expect the stat value to changes immediately when you set it

Comment: Hey thanks for the inspiration. I found a Solution which is pretty similar to what you have proposed. I have just made use of a useRef to handle both the inputs. I have isolated the value property from the state and kept only currency and url in the state. Now in the handleChange function, the inputRef's get changed. `input1Ref.current.value = input2Ref.current.value * rate;`